# A button is saying that the browser is wrong, even though it isn’t

Tags: javascript, html, code.org

I was testing a new milestone on a button I made in a Code.org Web Lab when, all of a sudden, it starts saying the browser I’m using doesn’t support the code.

I tried removing the new code I added, nothing happened. I tried fixing code errors, nothing happened. I even tried restoring the previous format of the code by copying and pasting code from a previous question, nothing happened.

Here's the current javascript code, including the new milestone:

```
<script>
      function clickCounter() {
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
          if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
          } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
          }
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "People have attempted but failed to help me <span id='recolor'>" + localStorage.clickcount + "</span> times.";

          if (localStorage.clickcount >= 100) {
            document.getElementById("recolor").style.color = "#bc5c18";
          }
          if (localStorage.clickcount >= 250) {
            document.getElementById("recolor").style.color = "#c9c9c9";
          }
          if (localStorage.clickcount >= 500) {
            document.getElementById("recolor").style.color = "#e5d860";
          }
          if (localStorage.clickcount >= 1000) {
            document.getElementById("recolor").style.color = "#6af2eb";
          }
          if (localStorage.clickcount >= 5000) {
            document.getElementById("recolor").style.color = "#42f456";
          }
          else {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support helping me.";
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

It stopped working only when I added the very last one.

Here's the code for the button that increases the counter:

```
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button"><b>HELP ME</b></button></p>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

I expected it to output this result:

`People have attempted and failed to help me x times`

but the actual output it gives is:

`Sorry, your browser doesn't support helping me.`

This result doesn't change no matter what I try. What do I do?

Comment: Won't it say that if the clickcount is less than 100? I mean I guess if you try clicking the button 100 times it'll change.

Comment: I've tried clicking more than 100 times, it doesn't work. And even if id did, it would still be weird to have it say that it isn't working the first 100 clicks.

Comment: you'd need clickcount >= 5000 before that message disappears ... that's how if/else works

Comment: as for button is saying the browser is wrong ... well ... this has nothing at all to do with the browser, it's your *code* that arbitrarily and incorrectly states the browser is wrong

Comment: How can I fix it to not say that message unless the browser isn't supported?

Comment: Add an `if(localStorage.clickcount < 100){...}` at the beginning

Comment: Where, exactly, would that go?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have `else if`

```
          if (localStorage.clickcount <= 100) {
            document.getElementById("recolor").style.color = "#bc5c18";
          }
          else if (localStorage.clickcount <= 250) {
            document.getElementById("recolor").style.color = "#c9c9c9";
          }
          else if (localStorage.clickcount <= 500) {
            document.getElementById("recolor").style.color = "#e5d860";
          }
          else if (localStorage.clickcount <= 1000) {
            document.getElementById("recolor").style.color = "#6af2eb";
          }
          else if (localStorage.clickcount <= 5000) {
            document.getElementById("recolor").style.color = "#42f456";
          }
          else {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support helping me.";
          }
```

Comment: I have a new problem: the recoloring of anything above bronze doesn't seem to work. I clicked it 250 times and it stay on the first color. Is there a fix for this as well?

Comment: you just need to replace `>` to `<`

Comment: Why don't you lower the number of clicks for testing at least ?